# Cannot identify date format using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating an .Net core project which reads from different types of .xlsx file and exports the data into a MongoDB collection. The "format", "number of columns" -etc of the input files are unknown. I am not having any issue identifying **decimal**, **boolean** & **string** datatypes. But when the cell values contains a **date**, OpenXML is reading it in **epoch string** format. As the Cell's **DataType** property is null, I have no ways to determine if I am reading a Date field or, not. Below is the code snippet that I am using for reading-

```
private static object GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument doc, Cell cell)
    {
        double res;
        string value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)  //Checking if it is a string
        {
            return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.GetItem(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
        }
        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.Boolean) //If contains boolean
        {
            return value == "1" ? true : false;
        }
        else
        {
            Double.TryParse(value, out res);
            if (res != 0)  //Determining if it is a Double value
            {
                return res;
            }

            return value;  //Otherwise the "InnerText" value will be passed
        }
    }
```

This seems to be working fine except for date formats. In that its getting converted to Decimal, which is messing up the data.

p.s.- The actual data type of the cells are general type and there is no way I can change in the input file. Also using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" package is not an option.

Comment: Just to be sure we're looking at the same thing, could you give us an example of the data 1) as it appears in Excel, 2) as it appears in the Open XML  and 3) as it appears when your code has processed it.

Comment: #1. Data in EXCEL "01-06-2017 00:00:52": 

#2. Data in Open XML: "42887.0005962269" (This is the InnerText value)

#3. Data after processing: 42887.0005962269 (i.e. after parsing as double)

Even if I can export the double value to Mongo, there will be no way to identify it as a date value afterwards. I need to identify it while reading the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm looking at this and your statement "The actual data type of the cells are general type" does not agree with what I'm seeing in Excel. If I use the double quotes around your sample date value then Excel considers it a string. If I leave the quotes away, Excel automatically formats the cell as a date. If I force the "General" cell formatting I see the 42887.etc. value, not a date. I can't see how the spreadsheet can contain what you describe...

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister, when I open the file in Excel, it is showing as a date. But, while I try to read the cell value using Open XML, the data type of the cell (cell.DataType) is containing null. And the "cell.CellValue.InnerText" is containing the epoch string equivalent of the date. And when I checked it again in the Mycrosoft Excel, the data type is shown as "general". But it's shown as a proper date format. I used MS Excel 2016. I will post a screen shoot soon.